# Create additional div on filtering using data attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a portfolio site that I'm trying to incorporate a small piece of extra functionality into. I've quickly exhausted my jQuery skills (in a depressingly short period of time!) and wondered if anyone can shed some light onto it.

The page is here: http://www.rodneyfitchassociates.com/specialism/

You'll see a pretty standard filtering portfolio which runs the following code:

```
 jQuery(function($){
      $(window).load(function() {
          $(".portfolio-filter a").click(function(){
              var selector = $(this).attr("data-filter");
              $(".'. $unique_classname .'").isotope({ filter: selector });
              $(this).parents("ul").find("a").removeClass("active");
              $(this).addClass("active");
              return false;
          });
      });
  });
```

The portfolio is filtered using this ul which triggers a hide/display effect dependent on the li selected:

```
<ul class="portfolio-filter clearfix">
    <li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="*"><span>All</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".portfolio-branding-specialisms"><span>Branding</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".portfolio-consulting"><span>Consulting</span></a></li>           
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".portfolio-culture"><span>Culture</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".portfolio-digital"><span>Digital</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to create an additional event that occurs when each list item is selected,  Specifically, I want a div that contains additional information about each element to appear somewhere else in the DOM.  The div may look something like this:

```
<div class="healthcare">
    <h1>Healthcare Description</h1>
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

****Update*****

I think I have have over-simplified the problem.  The ul is generated by some PHP which I've now added below the jQuery.  As a result I can't access the li items directly

```
$output .='
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $(window).load(function() {
        $(".portfolio-filter a").click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr("data-filter");
        $(".'. $unique_classname .'").isotope({ filter: selector });
        $(this).parents("ul").find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
        });

    });
});
</script>';
```

// Display filter links

```
$output .= '<ul class="portfolio-filter clearfix">';
$output .= '<li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="*"><span>'. __('All', 'wpex') .'</span></a></li>';
foreach ($terms as $term ) :
$output .= '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".portfolio-'. $term->slug .'"><span>'. $term->name .'</span></a></li>';
endforeach;
$output .= '</ul>';
```

Thanks for the help so far - I really appreciate it! :D

Comment: `$(".'. $unique_classname .'")` seems to be error here...?

Comment: Yep, until I added the PHP that follows the script and outputs the ul it doesn't make any sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


var array = {
  branding: ['this is title branding', 'this is branding desc'],
  consulting: ['this is title consulting', 'this is consulting desc'],
  culture: ['this is title culture', 'this is culture desc'],
  digital: ['this is title digital', 'this is digital desc'],
  all: ['this is title all', 'this is all desc'],
}
$(".portfolio-filter a").click(function () {
invisible = '<div class="invisible">  <h1></h1>  <p></p></div>';
var selector = $(this).data('filter');
item_div = $(this).children('span').text().toLowerCase();
title = array[item_div][0];
desc = array[item_div][1];
$('#container .invisible').remove();
$('#container').append(invisible);
$('.invisible h1').text(title);
$('.invisible p').text(desc);
$('.invisible').css('display', 'none');
$('.invisible').fadeIn(1000);
// $(".'. $unique_classname .'").isotope({ filter: selector });
$(this).parents("ul").find("a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
return false;
});
});
```

jsfiddle>
http://jsfiddle.net/27NUD/1/

So, span text = associative array keys. Array holds div(s) content(s). Div is created inside jquery block, so there is no need for html manipulation. (note: #container div = container of your 'title/description' div/box).

Comment: Huge thanks @nevermind - I think I may have omitted some key details though!

Comment: @AshLoudon, np, glad to help - now i see that Wordpress is in question... if categories will not be changed frequently - you can make pure jQuery solution (set titles and description in array(s) and relate it to li a classes names)... however - in this case, maybe php solution could be easier. :)

Comment: Categories will remain largely static once the site has been set, so if we could manage it in jQuery that would be preferable :)

Comment: thanks again.  Not had chance to get the code onto the site - I hope to later.  I'll let you know how I get on :)

Comment: Hi @nevermind - thanks for the update.  I'm unsure how I integrate this into the existing php code.  I've tried replacing the existing script with your code and also tried running it as a separate script after the existing one, but neither route seems to work.  I'm sure I'm doing something stupid over here!

Comment: @AshLoudon, huh, not sure, you will have to add some changes in wp .php files to make it work correct...

Comment: Hi @nevermind - yep that's what I did in the end.  It's messy, but it kinda works.  I'll keep refining it and post on here when it's fit for public consumption!  Thanks again :)

Comment: Np, glad i could help. Well, it could get messy with Wordpress... :)